# Hosting JavaFX on GH Pages

Tags: javafx, jar, github-pages, java-web-start

Is it possible to host a JavaFX application on github pages? Ideally I'd like the application to simply run (embedded into the webpage) when being forwarded to the page. I'm having trouble finding working examples online and would like to know if its even possible.

Answer (score 0):

At [OpenWebStart](https://openwebstart.com) you can find a [FAQ about starting a JavaFX based applications](https://github.com/karakun/OpenWebStart/blob/master/documentation/faq/FAQ.adoc#how-to-run-openjfx-based-javafx-applications-with-openwebstart) with JNLP. I hope that helps.